# How to send date and time from client to server using sockets

Tags: python, sockets

My client.py file is

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 1025))
message = s.recv(1024)
# This 1024 is for byte and not the port number
print(message.decode("utf-8"))
```

and my server.py file is

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(), 1024))
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1025))
# 1024 is the port no. The port no can be >= 1024 because the rest are reserved
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt, adr = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection to {adr} is established")
    clt.send(bytes("Socket programming in python", "utf-8"))
# Since bytes is used utf-8 tells what kind of byte is used
```

Now I want to send date and time from client to server
But I am new to socket programming so have no idea how to do it

Comment: Given that your code already does some sending of data (`clt.send` in the server) I can only imagine that you don't actually understand what the code is doing. In this case the first step would not to ask on how to change the code but that you should take the effort and actually understand the existing code. I recommend to study some introduction into socket programming in Python for this - there are many resources for this so just use a search engine and pick one which suits you best.

Comment: Do you know how to print the date and time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert date to a string and then send it.
So, the code for that would be,

```py
from datetime import date
dateAsString = str(date.today())

client.send(dateAsString.encode())
```